# Arbitrary index of model as root index of a view in Qt?

Tags: qt, model, proxy-classes

I'm wondering if it is possible to have multiple views onto a common model, where each view's root index is an arbitrary index in the common model in Qt?
Can this be achieved with a proxy model of some sort?

```
E.g.

source model:
root
 -A
   -1
   -2
 -B
   -3
   -4

Tree View:
 -A
   -1
   -2
 -B
   -3
   -4

List View1 (using index A as root):
 -1
 -2

List View2  (using index B as root):
 -3
 -4
```

Edit: So it seems the functionality I was trying to attain can be achieved by QTreeView.setRootIndex(). Unfortunately the QDeclarativeView doesn't offer this feature (yet?).

Answer (score 2):

Subclass `QAbstractProxyModel` and implement the `mapTo..` and `mapFrom..` methods so when the view's root is requested (an invalid `QModelIndex`) the desired root in the source model is returned.